# Extract Price - Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am attempting to extract the **first price (inc £)** from within the HTML.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="grid-item__price"><div class="inc-vat"><p class="price">
<span class="smaller currency-symbol">£</span>
        179.99
        <span class="vat-text"> inc. vat</span> </p></div>
<div class="ex-vat"><p class="price"><span class="smaller currency-symbol">£</span> 149.99 <span class="vat-text">ex. vat</span> </p></div>
</div>
```

**Python:**

```
for prices in products.find_all("div", {"class": "grid-item__price"}):
   print(prices)
```

**Expected Result:**

£179.99

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try calling the [`.next_sibling`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#next-sibling-and-previous-sibling) method since the expected output is `£` followed by the price (which is the next sibling).

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="grid-item__price"><div class="inc-vat"><p class="price">
<span class="smaller currency-symbol">£</span>
        179.99
        <span class="vat-text"> inc. vat</span> </p></div>
<div class="ex-vat"><p class="price"><span class="smaller currency-symbol">£</span> 149.99 <span class="vat-text">ex. vat</span> </p></div>
</div>"""


soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")

price_symbol = soup.find("span", class_="smaller currency-symbol")
print(price_symbol.text, price_symbol.next_sibling.strip())
```

Output:

```
£ 179.99
```